# How to make one variable of a tuple constant and another a variable?

Tags: swift

I have a tuple as a return value from a function. Like below

```
guard var (index, player) = self.getFielderSelected(coordinate: viewFielder.center) else { return }
```

but only player is modified. So I get a waring "Variable 'index' was never mutated; consider changing to 'let' constant". But if I make it let I can't modify player. Is there any way to make 'index' let and 'player' var.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get rid of the warning is to explicitly declare a variable to hold the result in the `guard` statement

```
guard var tuple: (index: Int, player: Player) = self.getFielderSelected(coordinate: viewFielder.center) else { return }
```

and then use this variable instead

```
tuple.player = ...
```

This will remove the warning since the variable `tuple` is modified.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution using pattern matching. It looks worse than the original variant, but much clearer than the variant with a variable for the tuple.

```swift
guard case .some((let index, var player)) = self.getFielderSelected(coordinate: viewFielder.center) else { return }
```